# How to get the xpath to get a text without a tag on the same level of other tags

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the XPath for `Search Results:`. However when I giving it 
`//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']`
it's not detecting the text, it's detecting the span

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
   <div class="col-xs-5" style="padding:0">
     <div>
       <span class="zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle" style="line-height:3.2">
          Search Results :
          <label class="ACadmincount"> 1 Matching Results</label>
       </span>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `XPath` with `selenium` to get text node like @Sunil Garg suggested (`//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']/text()`). It's syntactically correct `XPath` expression, but `selenium` doesn't support this syntax:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an
>    element.

It you want to get complete or partial text content of a particular element, you can use something like

*Python*

```
span = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']")
span.text # returns 'Search Results : 1 Matching Results'
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()', span) # returns 'Search Results :'
```

*Java*

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
WebElement span = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']")));
String text = span.getText();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim()", span);
```

Comment: Thanks Andersson, I tried the approach you have recommended. Selenium is not able to recognize the Xpath //span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']

Comment: What do you mean `not able to recognize`? Share exact exception

Comment: I am using the below code     String xpath="//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']";
   int xpathcount=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpath)).size();
   System.out.println("Size of the xpath : " +xpathcount);
   WebElement span= driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));

Comment: Try to add `ExplicitWait` like in updated answer. If you still get `NoSuchElementException`, check whether your `span` located inside an `iframe`

Answer (score 0):

To get text value use text() function

Here is the code

```
//span[@class='zeiss-font-Md aletssubtitle']/text()
```

Comment: Thanks Sunil, its recognizing the text in firepath.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, its recognizing the text in firepath. But selenium is not recognizing the element. I am trying to get the text 'Search Results :'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using CSS Selector as below:

```css
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.zeiss-font-Md.aletssubtitle)).getAttribute("innerText");
```

OR

```css
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.zeiss-font-Md.aletssubtitle)).getText();
```

Should also work.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you can try :

```
//*[text()='Search Results :']
```

Hope this will help you.